# How to execute the Stored procedure with output parameter in batch file using SQLCMD?

Tags: sql-server, windows, batch-file, sqlcmd

Below code is throwing an error while executing, it seems there is an issue with OUTPUT parameter.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET output_Variable = 1;

SQLCMD -S ServerName -d DbName -U UserName -P Password -Q"EXEC dbo.SP_TEST 'input_Param', 'input_Param', @output_param = %output_Variable% OUTPUT" -o C:\Error.txt
```

Comment: Either you specified all the parameter name `@para1 = xxx, @para2 = yyy` or you omit the parameter name `@para` totally `exec your_sp xxx, yyy`. You can't mix

Comment: remove the whitespace before and after `=` and remove the `;` as in `SET "output_Variable=1"`

Answer (score 0):

The standard `set` command for Windows `cmd` does not support whitespace before or after `=`. and you cannot define end of statement using `;` as that will become part of the variable's value. So currently you have:

```
SET output_Variable = 1;
```

Which results in a variable name having a trailing whitespace: `%output_Variable %` with a value containing a leading whitespace and a `;` i.e  `1;`

You need to remove the whitespace and the semicolon in standard `set` commands:

```
SET "output_Variable=1"
```

you can test the issue yourself by copying the following into a `cmd` window:

```
@echo off
SET output_Variable = 1;
set output_Variable
echo %output_Variable %
@echo on
```

Then repeat with the correct syntax:

```
@echo off
SET "output_Variable=1"
set output_Variable
echo %output_Variable%
@echo on
```

Comment: Thanks! Removed the whitespace and declared the input parameters as well but getting the following error, "Cannot use the OUTPUT option when passing a constant to a stored procedure."

Comment: That is now no longer part of the batch issue, you need to look at the sql structure now. Search for that error on SO. This only focused on your batch-file errors.